# Making an event like subscribing system for C++ * chars

Tags: c++, events, class, pointers, char

For simple data like ints or constants something like this would work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std ;

typedef void FuncInt (int) ;

class GraphElementProto {
public:
  void add (FuncInt* f)
{
  FuncVec.push_back (f) ;
} ;
  void call()
{
  for (size_t i = 0 ; i < FuncVec.size() ; i++)
    FuncVec[i] (i) ;
} ;  
private:
  vector<FuncInt*> FuncVec ;
} ;


static void f0 (int i) { cout << "f0(" << i << ")" << endl ; }
static void f1 (int i) { cout << "f1(" << i << ")" << endl ; }

int main() {
  GraphElementProto a ;
  a.add (f0) ;
  a.add (f1) ;
  a.call() ;
}
```

So now imagine we work with some data buffer like char.

We have threads that wait for data pointers and on appearance of that pointers want to change data at the same time. So we would need to create copy's of that data and give to each subscriber pointer to his own copy.

So how to do such thing? (sorry C++ nube - code is only thing I can understand)

Comment: I'm not C++ nube, but I understand your code much better than your question. please elaborate

Comment: I edited the question - now it seems better.)

Comment: I have to say I'm still not sure what you are trying to do ask/do there. If you have multiple threads trying to write to the same data copying would avoid  problems there, but you would have to think about how to merge it back together (afterall whats the point of modifying the data if no one sees the modification). But if you are new with c++ I would rather ask: do you have to use threads? Because c++ is hard enough at it is and threading brings a whole new bunch of headaches.

Comment: Ok - I'll try again - we have a graph. When first element creates data it needs to pass it to all subscribers (for example image generator passes data to encoder and it passes data to some streaming solution etc) so previous graph elements do not care to what will happen to data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the similarities between each node of the graph that you describe and create a class for them (class GraphElement below).  It should encapsulate its relationship to its child nodes, and it should do something locally with any incoming messages (function localAction).   You should then derive classes that represent specific variations - such as the image generator you mention - and change the local action.  Each class may take a copy of the original message, or change it as you need.

In my example code here I have create the default graph node - GraphNode - and made it simply print incoming messages before passing them to its child nodes.  I have used a string object for the incoming message - a lot nicer than a plain old C char * array [example: you can derive a string from char * when message2 is created in the code below].  I have made those object const references as its cheap, fast, and never changes the original.

I have derived a class called CatNode as an example of the variation you need. Objects of this type contain a history of all messages, and print out that history when a new message arrives.  Not very useful - but a good example none the less.  This demonstrates how each node may do anything to a copy of the original message - rewrite localAction().  It also passes that history to any child nodes - rewrite incomingMessage with a change to the parameter passed to deliverMessage().

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

class GraphNode
{
public:

  GraphNode( string & name ) : mChildren(), mName(name) {}
  GraphNode( const char * const name ) : mChildren(), mName(name==NULL?"":name) {}

  virtual void incomingMessage( const string & str ) {
    localAction(str);      // This node is to do something.
    deliverMessage(str);   // Child nodes are to do things too.
  }

  void addChild( GraphNode * child ) {
    mChildren.push_back( child );
  }

protected:

  // Rewrite this function for child classes who are to do different things with messages.
  virtual void localAction( const string & str ) {
    cout << mName << " : " << str << endl;
  }

  void deliverMessage( const string & str ) {
    vector<GraphNode*>::iterator itr = mChildren.begin();
    for( ; itr != mChildren.end(); ++itr ) 
      (*itr)->incomingMessage(str);
  }

  // Data members
  vector<GraphNode*> mChildren;
  string mName;

}; // [ GraphNode ]



class CatNode : public GraphNode
{
public:

  CatNode( string & name ) : GraphNode(name), mHistory() {}
  CatNode( const char * const name ) : GraphNode(name), mHistory() {}

  virtual void incomingMessage( const string & str ) {
    localAction(str);
    deliverMessage(mHistory);
  }

protected:

  virtual void localAction( const string & str ) {
    mHistory += str;
    cout << mName << " : " << mHistory << endl;
  }

  // Data members
  string mHistory;

}; // [ CatNode ]



main()
{
  // root -> childA
  GraphNode root("Root Node");
  CatNode childA("Child A");
  root.addChild( &childA );
  root.incomingMessage("Message1");
  cout << endl;

  // root -> childA -> childC
  //     \-> childB
  GraphNode childB("Child B");
  root.addChild( &childB );
  GraphNode childC("Child C");
  childA.addChild( &childC );
  string message2("Message2");
  root.incomingMessage(message2);

} // [ main ]
```

Comment: Fair enough.  You need editable copies of your object.  My answer doesn't meet your requirements. @Kabumbus

Comment: So... I upvoted on your grate posts a bit... so I hope you can edit your post... Can you provide any post update?)

Comment: I've completely rewritten the code to work in the graph context that you mention, using strings.  I hope this now works for you.